# Where are controller instances stored?

Tags: angularjs

If I add a controller to a DOM element with ng-controller, where is the resulting controller instance stored?

Is it added as a property of the DOM element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are stored on the DOM element. AngularJS uses the `data()` method of [the element API (aka JqLite)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to store the controller.

I've made [an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SSLNL/2/).

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
      link: function(scope,element) {
          scope.name = element.data('$ngControllerController').test();  
      }
   }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   this.test = function() {
       return "world";
   }
}
```

And yes, you can also access it with

```
angular.element('...').controller()
```

But you don't need Batarang for this. It's part of [the element API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods). This is the preferred way of obtaining access (or you can create a directive with a `require` attribute).

BTW, the scope is also stored this way, so you can get access to it via

```
element.data('$scope')
```

Comment: STEVER's code snippet also suggests this. For it to work and be consistent with what he wrote then angular would need to add the controller reference to the DOM object before returning it - which doesn't sound quite right.